# How to add a link in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have the following Javascript that I am using to make a sort of flowchart where the user clicks through a set of questions. For certain responses i want to link to an external site where more info can be found. How do I add these links?

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-corner" type="submit" data-bind="click: startOver, visible: queryData().id > 0">Start over</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container main">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="c12 text-center">
            <h1 data-bind="text: queryData().text"></h1>
            <h3 data-bind="text: queryData().subhead"></h3>
            <div class="option-group" data-bind="foreach: queryData().answers">
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" data-bind="click: $parent.goToTarget, text: text"></button>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-bind="click: stepBack, visible: navHistory().length > 1">Previous Step</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="push"></div>
    </div>


    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js?v=0.4.0"></script>

    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript is as follows:

JS

```
var queries = [{  
id: 0,
text: "Where to start?",
answers: [{
text: "Let's Begin!",
 target: 1
}]
}, {
id: 1,
text: "Which genre do you want to start in?",
  answers: [{
     text: "Fantasy",
     target: 100
    }, {
      text: "SciFi",
      target: 2
    }, {
      text: "Neither",
      target: 59
    }]
  }, {
   id: 2,
   text: "It's huge but it's worth it. The Cryptonomicon by Neal Stephenson",
   answers: [{
     text: "Amazon.co.uk",
     target: "_blank" 
   }, {
     text: "Amazon.com"
   }]
 }];




 function QueryViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.querySet = ko.observable();
  self.currentStep = ko.observable();
  self.queryData = ko.observable();
  self.sfw = ko.observable();
  self.navHistory = ko.observableArray();

  // Operations
  self.goToTarget = function(obj) {
  self.navHistory.push(self.currentStep());
  self.currentStep(obj.target);
  self.queryData(self.querySet()[obj.target]);
 }

  self.startOver = function() {
    self.navHistory.removeAll();
    self.goToTarget({target: 0});
  }

  self.stepBack = function() {
    var lastStep = self.navHistory().length > 1 ? self.navHistory.pop() : 0;
    self.currentStep(lastStep);
    self.queryData(self.querySet()[lastStep]);
  }

  var paramsString = document.location.hash.substring(1);
  var params = new Array();
  if (paramsString) {
  var paramValues = paramsString.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
  var paramValue = paramValues[i].split("=");
  params[paramValue[0]] = paramValue[1];
 }
   }

  params ? paramTarget = params['target'] : params = [];


  self.sfw() ? self.querySet(queriesSFW) : self.querySet(queries);
  if (paramTarget) {
    self.navHistory.push(0);
    self.currentStep(0);
    self.goToTarget({target: paramTarget})
  } else {
    self.goToTarget({target: 0});
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new QueryViewModel());
```

Comment: This is only the json data part. Please update the question with the html and js that you are using.

Comment: @AndrewL. That's not `json`, it's an object literal :P

Comment: @william clarke you *do* realize this `var self = this;` is nonsense? You keep referencing it after you close the bracket `}`. I fail to understand the point of this. In browser `self` is the `window` object, but I'm not sure if that's what you intended in your code.

Comment: @HectorBarbossa I have added in some further code for my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In html you can do something like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('https://google.com/', '_self')">Button</button>
```

You don't have to use a button, different elements can use `onclick` like text or images. This can also call js functions, just put the function name where "window.open..." is.

Of course the standard way to do it is

```
<a href='https://www.google.com/'>Link</a>
```

You can practice using js here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_inner_html
and learn more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp

I am not sure why you would show us the JSON for open a link to another page. Unless I misunderstood. This kind of basic information can be found by a quick Google search.

Answer (score -1):

Add your link in the object like:

```
text: "Fantasy",
link: "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
target: 2
```

Now when you need to go to that link, use this function:

```
var link = obj.link;
window.open(link, "_blank");
```

Comment: How do I call the function ?

Comment: Window.open is the function. Type it in!